# Load page if there is a session, else redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

So, basically, I want to do a very simple check, if there is not a session logged in, then I redirect the user to `signin.html`, I can do so by making a ajax request to my server in which it'll respond to me and then on the front-end I do something like

```
if(session){
    //continue
}else{
    window.location.href="signup.html"
}
```

However, my problem is that, for that 1 second or so that it takes the server to respond, since you can't use syncronous ajax requests anymore, my HTML keeps loading in the background allowing the user to see it for a split second, I'm trying to do something like if you were trying to access [www.youtube.com/account](http://www.youtube.com/account) without being logged in, it redirects you to google to sign in, without even loading its `account.html`. Also i'm kind of new to node... Hence my question... I think I might need to do this server-side, but I don't know how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put all of your HTML inside the `if (session) {` code block.

Comment: I think that a more correct approach would in fact be to let your server side code handle this logic as you alluded to in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express, you can use [res.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) to not send the view to the client until the session is logged in.

```
if(session){
    res.render(indexHtml);
}else{
    res.render(signupHtml);
}
```

Comment: Ok, where could I put this? Like, i need to put it inside something that happens once a redirect is triggered or something

Comment: You would put it in the callback for a route, something like `app.get('/', sessionCallback)`. So when the browser calls index.html (using '/' for the route is the same as '/index.html'), the express server will execute the session check and return the appropriate template.